# What is wrong in my answer? Subject: finding the integral of $\cot x$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals

$$\int \cot x \,dx=\int \frac{\cos x\sin x}{\sin^2 x}\,dx. $$
Assume $t= \sin^2 x$. Then $dt= 2\sin x\cos x \,dx$.
Using the identity:
$$ \sin 2x =2\sin x\cos x$$

$$\int \cot x \,dx=\int \frac{1}{2t}\,dt=\frac{1}{2}\ln(\sin x)^2+c $$
Can you help me find out what I did wrong? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: recall that $\ln a^b=b\ln a$

Comment: it is simpler to consider $t= \sin x$ and $dt=\cos x dx$

Comment: "Then dt=2sinx cosx"  There really should be a "dx" in there somewhere...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that

$$\frac12\ln(\sin(x))^2+c=\ln|\sin(x)|+c$$

Comment: According to your comment above, you should have $\frac{1}{2}\ln (\sin x)^2 = \ln \sin x$ and not $\ln \lvert \sin x\rvert$. Maybe you should spend a couple of words on this...

Comment: @Gibbs by the substitution proposed that holds because $\sqrt{\sin^2x}=|\sin x|$

Comment: It's not for me, it is just for the asker, who accepted your answer but might have not noticed this detail.

Comment: @Gibbs Yes of course, you are absolutely right it is a correct observation to put to the attention of the asker! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can do even less: notice that $\cot x = \frac{\cos x}{\sin x}$ and that the derivative of $\sin$ is $\cos$. Hence
$$\int \cot x \,dx = \int \frac{\cos x}{\sin x}\,dx = \log \lvert \sin x \rvert + c, c \in \mathbb{R}.$$

Answer (score 2):

your work is correct. $$\int \cot x \,dx=\int \frac{1}{2t}\,dt=\frac{1}{2}\ln(\sin x)^2+c =\ln\lvert \sin x\rvert +c.$$

I am surprised that you did not make the integration simpler by,

$$\int \cot x \,dx=\int \frac{\cos x}{\sin x}\,dx =   \int \frac{du}{u}   =\ln\lvert \sin x\rvert +c. $$

Answer (score 1):

Your integrand is correct:

$$\int \cot x\, dx = \int \frac{1}{2} \frac{dt}{t} = \frac{1}{2} \log\lvert t \rvert + C.$$
The issue is just with your final substitution:
$$\frac{1}{2} \log\lvert t\rvert + C = \frac{1}{2} \log( \sin^2x) + C = \log\lvert \sin(x)\rvert + C.$$